# Is it okay to ask multiple questions of the same topic in a single question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is it okay to ask multiple questions of the same topic in a single question? I am not asking but I have noticed some questions like these:

- [Timed out in cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1792/540)
- [Cricket ground specifications](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2298/540)
- [Is it a catch/dismissal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2111/540)
- [Who are involved in the team selection process in cricket?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2090/540)
- [Team sports in olympics](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1813/540)
- [Career of a cricketer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1785/527)

All of above questions are asked by the same user. I am not criticising him but just asking whether it is okay or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question can standalone when asked, it should be asked separately.

However, the user's group of questions asked separately would involve [repetition](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/career-of-a-cricket-player#comment3215_1785).

If repetition is involved and the group of questions do not standalone, then I'm fine with the grouping of questions. I am not knowledgeable in cricket so if questions could be asked separately, please speak up. I have already attempted to [discourage](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/team-sports-in-olympics#comment3252_1813) this practice where necessary.

Comment: Ok. So if questions are very closely related (which can be answered in the same answer), we should ask it in group.

Comment: @hims056 Don't take it as a rule-of-thumb, but if you feel that your group of questions would benefit from such a format, go for it. The [cricket ground specifications](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/cricket-ground-specifications) question is acceptable in that the main focus of the question is on the characteristics of international cricket grounds.

Comment: @hims056 [Here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2323/527) is an example of myself asking multiple questions in the same question.