# How do we tag questions encompassing multiple leagues?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/conversation/tags-encompassing-north-american-major-leagues-and-professional-leagues-in-genera) (and in a [previous meta post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/tagging-questions-about-north-american-major-leagues)), it was discussed how we should tag questions about multiple leagues.

In the previous meta post, I said it didn't make sense to create a tag encompassing leagues as:

- that type of question (financial/contract issues) is best served separately
- that type of question wasn't primarily about the leagues, but primarily about financial/contract issues (and it was [pointed out in one question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/do-minor-league-baseball-clubs-pay-the-players#comment11585_5074) that the structure is very different between two leagues, thus the request to ask the question separately)

After the discussion in chat, I do realize that such a tag is reasonable and although some questions are best served separately, some questions can be best served in combination if it is [about the same topic](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/is-it-okay-to-ask-multiple-questions-of-the-same-topic-in-a-single-question). I suggested [major-leagues](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/major-leagues) for major North American leagues and [professional](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional) for professional leagues in general.

Here are the questions that would be affected by this suggested change:

- [Teams in North American leagues that won their first game ever?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14276/teams-in-north-american-leagues-that-won-their-first-game-ever)
- [Can a Hall of Fame player come out of retirement and play again](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15707/can-a-hall-of-fame-player-come-out-of-retirement-and-play-again)
- [Which teams has won the most titles in the four major American Sports?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/which-teams-has-won-the-most-titles-in-the-four-major-american-sports)
- [Is it possible to purchase another teams draft pick?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15576/is-it-possible-to-purchase-another-teams-draft-pick)
- [Has a college team ever played against a professional team?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/has-a-college-team-ever-played-against-a-professional-team)
- [Why are American teams always named in a certain format?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15233/why-are-american-teams-always-named-in-a-certain-format)
- [What is the legal basis for fining players for out-of-game actions?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/what-is-the-legal-basis-for-fining-players-for-out-of-game-actions)
- [How many times have major league teams won a championship after winning 4 Game 7s?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/how-many-times-have-major-league-teams-won-a-championship-after-winning-4-game-7)
- [How often do 0-0 scores at the completion of regulation occur in major sports?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/how-often-do-0-0-scores-at-the-completion-of-regulation-occur-in-major-sports)
- [Additional questions not tagged with the leagues, but might apply as well](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+nfl+mlb+nba+nhl+-%5Bnfl%5D+-%5Bmlb%5D+-%5Bnba%5D+-%5Bnhl%5D)

**How do we tag questions encompassing multiple leagues?**

Comment: Maybe this can be also added to your list - as a possible candidate for (professional) tag? [Is Tom Glavine the only hockey player who was drafted by the NHL, but went on to play another professional sport?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/5433)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a valid case for a [major-leagues](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/major-leagues) tag (or perhaps [us-major-leagues](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-major-leagues)) as that's commonly used as a way of cutting down the scope of a broad question to make it reasonably answerable.

My more general take here is much as it ever is: let's create a tag if we find that it would actually be useful; if we find a group of leagues which are commonly being used on questions, then create a tag for it, but there's no need to be proactive about it. I don't think we've got any other candidates at the moment, but always happy to have examples pointed out :-)

Comment: Proactive insofar that 1) it was first pointed out 4 years ago 2) I brought it up recently in chat. I'm saying if there is a case (to which you agree with), let's make those changes. The "[Why are American teams always named in a certain format?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/15233)" is a great candidate for the tag being useful as 1) NHL wasnt included but would (and should) apply to the question being asked, 2) tagging with 5 leagues leaves no room for other applicable tags, and 3) it's a good example of a question that is focused enough to merit a [tag:major-leagues] or equivalent tag.

Comment: I agree with @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ, if we don't have such tag, with the 5 tag limit per question users can't properly categorize their questions. I've had to use "international-sports" before to get around this https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/how-many-times-major-league-teams-have-won-championship-by-winning-4-game-7s

Comment: Added the major-leagues tag for this question https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/north-american-major-league-teams-with-most-championships-won-on-the-road-before

Comment: @alamoot I'm all for tagging and addressing these questions, but lack of consensus (and the lack of [accepted threshold](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37966800#37966800) for such) is preventing that at the moment.